# How to concatenate two strings in MIPS?

Tags: mips, string-concatenation, spim

```
concat:
    lb $t0, 0($a0)                   # $t0 = string1[i]
    beq $t0, $0, string2             # if end of string1, go to string2
    sb $t0, 0($a2)                   # stringconcat[i] = string1[i]
    addi $a0, $a0, 1                 # increment index into string1
    addi $a2, $a2, 1                 # increment index into stringconcat
    j concat                         # loop back

string2:
    lb $t0, 0($a1)                   # $t0 = string2[j]
    beq $t0, $0, done                # if end of string2, return
    sb $t0, 0($a2)                   # stringconcat[j] = string2[j]
    addi $a1, $a1, 1                 # increment index into string2
    addi $a2, $a2, 1                 # increment index into stringconcat

done:
    sb $0, 0($a2)                    # append null to end of string
    jr $ra
```

I'm new to MIPS and I have this code as an assignment and I don't know what to add to make it run on QtSpim please help.

Comment: Exception occurred at PC=0x00400024

Comment: Likely a null pointer exception on the first instruction if you haven't set `$a0` to anything.

Comment: @user3724875 I'm using Mars software for running Mips assembly program and it's very good.  download link:http://cld.persiangig.com/download/E68KaQp7cj/Mars4_3.jar/dl

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a jump back to `string2` at the end of your second loop.

```
string2:
  lb $t0, 0($a1)
  beq $t0, $0, done
  sb $t0, 0($a2)
  addi $a1, $a1, 1
  addi $a2, $a2, 1
  j string2                        # Missing line!
```

---

For the sake of completeness, bellow is a fully working program based on your code. It concatenates strings: `"Bull"` and `"Dozer"` into: `"BullDozer"`:

```
.data
  first: .asciiz "Bull"
  second: .asciiz "Dozer"
  .align 2
  result: .space 10       #10 bytes for result: strlen("Bull") + strlen("Dozer") + 1
  .align 2

.globl main
.text
  main:
    la $a0, first
    la $a1, second
    la $a2, result

  concat:
    lb $t0, 0($a0)          # $t0 = string1[i]
    beq $t0, $0, string2    # if end of string1, go to string2
    sb $t0, 0($a2)          # stringconcat[i] = string1[i]
    addi $a0, $a0, 1        # increment index into string1
    addi $a2, $a2, 1        # increment index into stringconcat
    j concat                # loop back

  string2:
    lb $t0, 0($a1)          # $t0 = string2[j]
    beq $t0, $0, done       # if end of string2, return
    sb $t0, 0($a2)          # stringconcat[j] = string2[j]
    addi $a1, $a1, 1        # increment index into string2
    addi $a2, $a2, 1        # increment index into stringconcat
    j string2               # **Missing line!**

  done:
    sb $0, 0($a2)           # append null to end of string
    jr $ra
```